# Regex to match a list, disallow trailing comma

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a validation rule parser.

Here's a regex that is meant to verify if a rule is complete and valid:

```
/^\w+ \| (?: (?:\w+ | \w+=\{(?:[\w.]+,?)+\} | \w+=[\w.]+) (?:,|$) )+$/ix
```

What I want to match is a string of this format:

```
identifier | options
```

Where `options` is a comma-separated list of:

- `flag` (sequence of `\w`)
- `key=value`
- `list={1,2,45,foo_bar,with.dot}`

It works, but has some issues with trailing commas:

1. This should not match (trailing comma at the end):

   ```
   potato|lemon,aa=bb,list={12,45,a.b,_s},foo,yes=no,
   ```
2. And trailing comma at the end of a list:

   ```
   potato|lemon,aa=bb,list={12,45,a.b,_s,},foo,yes=no
   ```

Suggestions welcome - feel free to [tinker](http://regex101.com/r/hF3pO2/2).

Comment: my first thought is to check the string for specifics outside of the regex. is that possible?

Comment: You mean to replace `,}`=>`}` and drop trailing comma? I thought of that, but I hoped for a regex solution. That's a plan B.

Comment: Do you need to support for spaces between syntax elements? like `list = {1, 2,45,  foo_bar , with.dot}` for example?

Comment: @Icoderre Don't worry about whitespace, I'm discarding it beforehand. The string is clean.

Comment: @MightyPork maybe you can help yourself by replacing `,}` for `}` and also for the latest `,` manually. Or add a negative lookahead for lists and for the last comma

Comment: @Fede I know, that's what I am doing now as a workaround. But there surely is some regex way..

Comment: Alright, I found a solution. But if you guys want, you can still answer and get the 25 points :)

Comment: @MightyPork for the list you can do also a regex workaround by changing `(?:[\w.]+ ,?)+` to `(?:[\w.]+ ,[\w.]+)+` but this will enforce that you have at least 2 elements in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to check the syntax, you can use :

```
\A\w+\|(\w++(?:=(?:{[\w.]++(?>,[\w.]+)*}|[\w.]+))?)(?:,(?1))*\z
```

[see the demo *(in multiline mode)*](http://regex101.com/r/sL4eR0/15)

Comment: Hah! `(?1)` .. Nice thought.

Comment: This is really fast, and interesting (I've never seen a thing like `(?1)` before.. I'll first evaluate Icoderre's updated solution though.

Comment: @MightyPork: `(?1)` refers to the subpattern in the first capturing group itself. It's not a backreference, it is an alias.

Comment: We both seem to end up with the same results, although this regex is conceptually better in my opinion. It clearly states that a comma is only followed by another pattern.

Comment: @lcoderre: thanks but with regexes "conceptually" can be far from the most performant way.

Comment: Ok, I'll go with this. It's both elegant and fast.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Just a clarification, how do `\A` and `\z` differ from `^` and `$`?

Comment: @MightyPork: `\A` and `\z` are always the start and the end of the string whatever the mode (multiline or not). And `$` in "normal" mode can match two things: the end of the string or the last end of line if there is a newline character before the end of the string *(However, this behaviour can be disabled with the `/D` global modifier.)*

Comment: @MightyPork: Note that this particularity of `$` is only true with PCRE (as far i know).

Comment: @MightyPork: to be more clear about `$`: if the string is `a\n\n` *(where `\n` represents a newline)* the pattern `/a\n$\n/` will match the string but the pattern `/a\n$\n/D` will fail.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated solution:** Since you don't need specific group matching, I just go ahead and check after a comma if there is another character. This implies every matching alternative must start with `\w` (I matched in the demo just for visual understanding)

So  `(?:,\w)` for the `list={X,Y,Z}` and  `(,\w)?` for the end of string.

Check it out: http://regex101.com/r/hF3pO2/7

`^ \w+ \| (?: (?:  \w+   |  \w+=\{ (?:[\w.]+ (?:,\w)?)+ \}  |  \w+=[\w.]+  ) (,\w)? )+$`

With `gixm` flags

---

**Old (close but not quite) solution:**

I am not a super pro in regexes, so maybe there is a better way, but I could verify the end of the string is not a `,$` with this:

`(?:,[^$]|[^,]$)`

So I added that for the `list={X,Y,Z}` and for the end of the line. The whole regex now looks like this:

`^ \w+ \| (?: (?:  \w+  |  \w+=\{ (?:[\w.]+ (?:,[^$]|[^,]$)?)+ \}  |  \w+=[\w.]+  )(?:,[^$]|[^,]$) )+$`

... Have a look http://regex101.com/r/hF3pO2/3

Comment: I'm not sure about the `[^$]` bit, but it is certainly faster than my solution.

Comment: It's got some problems, if you resolve it, it'll be great. Eg. this is not matched: `aa|list={a.b,_s}`

Comment: Yes, I eagerly answered, but with a bad test case. Sorry about that. Here is another solution.

Comment: Yeah now it works, but it's super slow :/ Check here for a faster modification: http://regex101.com/r/wO9qT0/3 (using possessive quantifiers)

Comment: Oh, false positive: This matches: `afsa|sg,aa={aa,ss}j`

Comment: Wow, I didn't think I would learn two important new things on regexes in this thread. Thanks for the possessive quantifiers. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my own solution here as well, just for completeness:

`^ \w+ \| (?: (?: \w++ | \w++=\{(?:[\w.]++ (?:,(?!\}))?)+\} | \w++=[\w.]++ ) (?:,(?!$))? )+ $`

I'm not sure if it's correct, but I tried it and it worked, so hopefully. ([try it](http://regex101.com/r/wO9qT0/2))

Answer (score 0):

There's better way to write this kind of regexp in a grammar-like way:

```
/
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<entry> (?&identifier) \| (?&options) )
  (?<identifier> \w+ )
  (?<options> (?&option) , (?&options) | (?&option) )
  (?<option> (?&list) | (?&keyvalue) | (?&flag) )  
  (?<flag> \w+ )
  (?<keyvalue> (?&key) = (?&value) )
  (?<key> \w+ )
  (?<value> \w+ )
  (?<list> list= \{ (?&list_entries) \} )
  (?<list_entries> (?&list_entry) , (?&list_entries) | (?&list_entry) )
  (?<list_entry> [A-Za-z0-9._]+ )
)  
^(?&entry)$
/x
```

See it in action: https://regex101.com/r/hF3pO2/10

It's easier to understand and tweak, however there are certain quirks. One is that left recursion doesn't work (you cannot use `options: options "," option | option` rule, you have to specify it as `options: option "," options | option`). Another is that you can only use it for validation, you cannot extract data with this kind of pattern, as rules in `(?(DEFINE))` block do not capture.

Based on Nikita Popov's article on how powerful (and not really regular) PCRE regexps are: https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html